# "black hole" for minimized windows

Tags: ubuntu, kde, window

I have Dell-Precision laptop with ubuntu 14.04 installed; using KDE. As a result of my minor (and failed) attempts to get an extra widget into bottom bar, something funny happened:

Whenever I call a window (any! including browser, etc) by clicking on that window icon (either at the bottom bar or at the desktop icon), and after using it, click at the "minimize button" in that window,

the window does NOT go as an "waiting icon"  into icon bar, but simply disappears!  I know it is somewhere (I can see it by using "ps" command), but it is lost to me if I want to call it back (e. g. to maximize). There  must be some minor fix, but I cannot figure it out... Help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on an Ubuntu derivative, but only with *Brasero*. Reset KDE settings, if needed just re-install the desktop environment.

Comment: thanks, Akito;  but can you be more specific : "Reset KDE settings" -- what specifically I need to reset in "System setting"? If possible, can you give me step-by-step instruction ? (see, you have here a dumb user, sigh...)

Comment: Dumb people are those who don't ask questions. I didn't put a step-by-step guide in, because I don't know much about KDE. But I will look into it and update my answer in case I find a more specific solution